# selection not showing up in drop down box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

i'm having trouble getting the status of a particular row in the database to be used as the selection for the drop-down menu in a report i've build in rails (3).
Here's the relevant piece:

```
<% @report.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map {|d| [d.status, d.status]}), :selected => row.status %>
    </td>
```

one row in the database has status of 'follow up'

but all the drop down boxes are defaulting to 'delivered'

Answer (score 0):

i was confused between this and the form_for construct.
in the form_for, you'd say:

```
form_for @object...
    <%=f.select options_for_select(), :selected => :object.field %>
```

here it suffices to say:

```
<% @report.each do |row| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Distribution.select(:status).group(:status).order(:status).map {|d| [d.status, d.status]}, row.status) %>
    </td>
```